# Launching and Getting a String value from other application using ResultOfActivity

Tags: android

I have two application in android: app 1 and app 2, from my app 1, i want to call the app 2 to perform some activity and return a string value using result of activity. Now my problem is, i already perform to call the app 2 from my app 1, but from my on Result Activity, when the app 2 is finish (), there is no value returned from my app 1. Please help me good programmers. Thanks

My App1 Code :

```
private void btnVerify() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageButton verify = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        verify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(VoteActivity.this, "Verifying Camera Loading..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                Intent i = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("org.opencv.samples.fd");
                startActivityForResult(i, 0); 
            }


        });
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle res = data.getExtras();
            resv = (String) res.get("regid");
    //      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TEST1"+resv, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

my app 2 code :

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {   

                        vname = mView.saveValues(aw);
                        Intent person = new Intent();
                        Bundle backpack = new Bundle();
                        backpack.putString("regid",vname);
                        person.putExtras(backpack);
                        setResult(RESULT_OK,person);
                        finish();

                    }
                });
```

App 1 android manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.votingapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".VoteActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_vote" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_reg" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".VerifyActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_verify" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Verification"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_verification" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

App 2 Android manifest  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="org.opencv.samples.fd"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
                      android:smallScreens="true" 
                      android:normalScreens="true" 
                      android:largeScreens="true" 
                      android:anyDensity="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity android:name="FdActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: in onActivityResult Bundle res is not null ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir.. Sir please help me. When i make it toast . it didn't perform. My if condition from the function onResultActivity doesn't executed

Comment: does your onactivityresult gets triggered? add log.v(tag,value) to see if it gets triggered

Comment: how can i log my onactivityresult ? .. i tried to toast it 
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
   Bundle res = data.getExtras();
   resv = (String) res.get("regid");
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TEST1"+resv, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
but it didn't perform

Comment: try instead of showing a toast use the logcat , put this in onActivityResult  >  Log.d("ACTIVITYNAME", "Getting result is being called and the value is: " + resv);   then watch the logcat and see if its printed

Comment: when i put the log inside the if condition sir, i didn't receive any values within it!

Comment: sir please help me with this problem. . the logcat doesn't executed.